# Login with Facebook not returning Email id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using the following code for facebook login. I have implemented the same code before. It was working. But now, while trying with a new project, its not returning email id. But returning, auth_id, name, etc

```
    <?php

    require 'facebook/facebook.php';
    require 'config/fbconfig.php';
    require 'config/functions.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => APP_ID,
                'secret' => APP_SECRET,
                ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
        if (!empty($user_profile )) {
            # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)

            $username = $user_profile['name'];
            $uid = $user_profile['id'];
             $email = $user_profile['email'];


             print_r($user_profile);
             die();



        } 
    } 

//something else
?>
```

the output of `print_r($user_profile);` is:

> Array ( [name] => Gijo Varghese [id] => 95431400XXXXXXX )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don´t ask for the email field, so of course it does not get returned:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=name,email');
```

Also, you need to ask for the `email` permission in the authorization process. But since it worked for you before, it´s most likely about Declarative Fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4